# Cannot get the "South Arrow" icon to show on my html button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am trying to get a "South arrow" to show on a Button I have created using an HTML page with JQuery UI set up.  I have my html as follows:

```
    <button id="AccountListButton"class="btn accountLister" style="margin-left: -4px" data-bind="jqAutoCombo: 'AccountList'">...</button>
```

I have added the following to my script on the page (right after my knockout applyBindings:

```
    $(".accountLister").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-gear", secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" } });
```

No matter what i do, all i get is a bootstrap styled button with ... in the view.  What am i doing wrong?

I've tried the suggestions at [JQuery UI Button Icons not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413226/jquery-ui-button-icons-not-displaying) but still no luck

Comment: Typically, the images that jquery UI uses have to be in the sub-folder called "Images". So if jquery.ui is located as path : /Scripts/jquery.ui , then the images should be located at : /Scripts/Images/. Check the path and see if you have discripencies.

Comment: Did you make sure to include the CSS for a theme?  Did you place the `$(".accountLister") ... ` code after a `$(function() {` call?

Comment: I'm doing this in an MVC5 app with the bundle set up on the themes.  I used the NuGet package to add it JQueryUI to the project.  Everything is in "~/Content/themes/base/...."  There is an images folder under the base folder.  Do I need to add the images to the StyleBundle i set up for the JQueryUI CSS?

Comment: Show your View-Model.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JavaScript looks like this..

```
$(function() {
    $(".accountLister").button({
         icons: {
             primary: "ui-icon-gear",
             secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
         }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/4k1kkf3c/)